# How to get specific text after matching delimiter?

Tags: bash

I have this in my bash script:

```
CONFIG=$(docker inspect "${CONTAINER}" | jq '.[0].Config.Env')
```

`CONFIG` now looks something like this (as a string):

```
[ "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin", "site_title=Example", "admin_email=test@test.com", "site_url=www.test.com" ]
```

What I want is to get the `site_url` so I tried:

```
cut -d "site_url=" -f 2 <<< "${CONFIG}"
```

But with `cut` I can only set a one character delimiter.

How can I achieve my goal of getting `www.test.com` from `"site_url=www.test.com"`

Comment: try using awk instead of cut.

Answer (score 1):

Can you just use `jq` again?

```
SITE_URL=$(echo $CONFIG | jq -r '.[1]' | cut -f2- -d=)
```

Answer (score 1):

used `awk` split function to split the row into two parts and then extracted what is needed.

```
awk '{split($0,a,"site_url="); gsub(/]|\"/,"", a[2]) ;print a[2]}'
```

Comment: think you can do it simpler with awk, without using any built in functions.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
echo [ "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin", "site_title=Example", "admin_email=test@test.com", "site_url=www.test.com" ] | awk -F",|=|]" '{ print $8 } '
```

Or in your case simply:

```
echo ${CONFIG} | awk -F",|=|]" '{ print $8 } '
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grep -o` with `cut`:

```
grep -o 'site_url=[^"]*' <<< "$CONFIG" | cut -d= -f2
www.test.com
```